# Is this Square Track Cam valid?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I want to convert rotary motion (the orange propeller) onto a square path (the dark gray path). Is this a valid way to go about it? Would it be possible to use a square peg instead of a round one (the red circle) in order to keep the peg level as it travels? If not how could I keep it level? I'm a noob.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Update** 2015/11/16 - Posted another option as an answer below

[image]

Comment: From a materials standpoint: corners are stress concentrators and could wear down rapidly. May consider using slightly rounded corners on the inside of the track.

Comment: @starrise Thanks. Are you referring exclusively to the inner corners or square design in general.

Comment: To reduce wear and stress in the corners & to have a smoother travel for the red peg, the path followed by the red peg should form part of a circle in the corners. Both sides of the channel the red peg is in should be curved at the corners.

Comment: @Fred Is there a rule of thumb for how much they should be rounded?

Comment: The width of the channel followed by the red peg needs to be uniform throughout. This is easily done on the straights; a bit more difficult to do on the corners. Ensure the curvature on the inside and outside of the channel produces a uniform thickness; the same as on the straights. As to the size of the curvature, it comes down to what you want to achieve: too much curvature will produce a quasi circle - not what you want, too little curvature & you end up with high resistance to movement at the corners.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an existing method using a [reuleaux triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuleaux_triangle#Mechanism_design). It was used for moving film in a stepwise motion in projectors.

[image]

Comment: So many moving pieces! I'd like to find something simpler, but I'll consider this.

Answer (score 4):

If you're going with square peg and don't strictly restrict its rotation (e.g. with mechanism like in Ratchet freak's answer), you WILL run into problems with technical tolerances - it will be catching on the corners and with any other shape than round you will have this problem.

[image]

Your original image mechanism can work okay, but modifying the peg to be square will break it.

Answer (score 1):

The reuleaux triangle is a great solution but I would prefer something that has fewer parts and is more compact...

Here's another option. The idea is to sandwich a bent peg between offset tracks. So the sandwich goes like this: Bottom Track, peg, Propeller, Top Track (Transparent). And Yes, I would round out the track corners more than depicted.

[image]